# Is there a way in sqlplus to return lowercase col aliases?

Tags: oracle, perl, sqlplus

I'm using something like

```
SELECT MYCOL as mycol from table;

MYCOL
______
1
2
2
3
```

I want:

```
mycol
_____
1
2
2
3
```

I can lc the result with Perl but I'd prefer that the `fetchrow_hashref()` return lc hashkeys. I tried

```
SELECT MYCOL as LOWER(mycol) from table;
```

which predictbly errored.

Is there a way to do this in SQLPLUS?

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
$dbh->{FetchHashKeyName} = 'NAME_lc';
```

(or do it just on the statement handle) to make DBI convert all returned column names to lower case.

Comment: Thank you sirs, these are very helpful answers. I actually *considered* quoting the "as" names but I'd already convinced myself it wouldn't work!

Answer (score 1):

You can quote an alias to return wanted name of some column

```
SELECT MYCOL as "mycol" from table;
```

or

```
SELECT MYCOL as "MyCol" from table;
```

Comment: Double-quoting worked like a charm! (but single-quotes errored!?)Thanks again.

Comment: I believe (later versions of?) the sql standard specify it must be double quotes.  Only some sql implementations allow either.